# Uploading PNG to S3 using aws-sdk in node not completing

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am seeing an issue when I try to upload a PNG image to my S3 bucket using aws-sdk in Node.js.  This is the code I am executing:

```
function uploadScreenshot (filePath, fileName) {
    var body = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/image.png');

    body.on('end', function() {
        console.log("Finished reading in file.")
    });

    var s3obj = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: 'bucketname',
            Key: 'remoteimage.png',
            Body: body,
            ContentType: 'image/png'
        }
    });

    s3obj.upload({
        Body: body
    }).on('success', function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }).on('error', function(error, response) {
        console.log(error);
    }).on('complete', function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    }).send();
}
```

When I execute my code I do see the image being uploaded in the console but I never see it in the bucket.  I also don't see any errors.  Here is the output when I execute:

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.1.10.80:52457/wd/hub
Build Identifier -> f616fd40-ebc3-11e5-baa4-937904718be4
Finished reading in file.
{ loaded: 16384, total: 44318, part: 1, key: 'remoteimage.png' }
{ loaded: 32768, total: 44318, part: 1, key: 'remoteimage.png' }
{ loaded: 44318, total: 44318, part: 1, key: 'remoteimage.png' }
Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

You can see from above the entire file is streamed (44318 bytes) but it doesn't get saved in my S3 bucket.  I also tried by using the putObject method but that doesn't work either.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Another thing I noticed is none of the logging in the success, complete or error events are ever executed.  The logging in the httpUploadProgress event is the only one executed.